# How can you put in a colorized code into the question?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my code blocks formatted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-get-my-code-blocks-formatted)

Is there some script, or something else that is used within the Stack Overflow's editor to put in syntax highlighting for code when posting a programming-related question?

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stack-overflow-work-the-official-faq

Comment: Umm...I do not see anything about colorizing code in there? I followed the link ...which lead to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258998/how-do-i-get-my-code-formatted-in-stackoverflow and the answer is.. 'This doesn't appear to be addressed in the unofficial FAQ yet, so if the question and answers were made community wiki, this could perhaps be added. – Chris Marasti-Georg Nov 3 '08 at 15:39'

Comment: It's in the FAQ index now, but this question has been asked *many times* on meta in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: screenshot with freehand circle]

- paste your code
- select it
- click the little binary icon (pictured)
- profit!

Comment: You're a gem...I feel so stupid for not recognizing that...embarrassing actually...now I know why I got a downvote...sheepish..

Comment: You've found the step before the Profit?

Comment: the downvote wasn't from me!

Comment: BTW for me that button looks something like this `{}`